# Preferred method of downloading large files from AWS S3 to EC2 server

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm having some intermittent problems downloading a largeish (3.5GB) file from S3 to an EC2 instance. about 95% of the time, it works great, and fast - maybe 30 seconds. However, that 5% of the time it stalls out and can take > 2 hours to download. Restarting the job normally solves this problem - indicating that the problem is transient. This is making me think there is a problem with how I'm downloading files. Below is my implementation - I pipe the read stream into a write stream to disk and return a promise which resolves when it is done (or rejects on error).

Is this the preferred method of downloading large files from S3 with node.js? Are there any "gotchas" I should know about?

```
function getDownloadStream(Bucket, Key) {
  return s3
  .getObject({
    Bucket,
    Key
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return Promise.reject(`S3 Download Error: ${error}`);
  })
  .createReadStream();
}

function downloadFile(inputBucket, key, destination) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    getDownloadStream(inputBucket, key)
    .on('end', () => {
      resolve(destination);
    })
    .on('error', reject)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destination));
  });
}
```

Comment: Does it work successfully if you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've not tried - like I said, 95% of the time, it works perfectly - its just random occurrences that fail, for no reason I can tell - once they restart they work again

Answer (score 0):

By default traffic to s3 goes through internet so download speed can become unpredictable. To increase the download speed and for security reasons you can configure aws endpoints, which is a virtual device and it can be used for routing the traffic between your instance to s3 through their internal network(much faster) than going through internet.

While creating endpoint service for s3, you need select route tables of the instances where the app is hosted. after creating you will see a entry in those route tables like `destination (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3)` -> `target     vpce-xxxxxx`, so when ever traffic goes to s3 it is routed through the endpoint instead of going through internet.

Alternatively you can also try parallelising the download like downloading range of bytes in parallel and combine it but for 3.5GB above approach should be fine.